# What happens when you use DISTINCT * in COUNT() in SQL?

Tags: sql

I've just learned about the COUNT() function, and how it is possible to get the number of rows in a column by passing * as the argument.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

I've also learned that we can get the number of distinct rows of a column in a table by using DISTINCT.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column) FROM table;
```

I've noticed that the following returns nothing.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) FROM table;
```

Why is this?

I suppose the root of my issue is that I don't quite fully understand what the COUNT() function with * as the argument does exactly. My resource says that the COUNT() function takes a column as an argument and counts how many non-NULL rows there are. So say we have a table that has a column with some rows having both NULL and non-NULL values. If COUNT(column) doesn't count the non-NULL rows, what happens differently in COUNT(*) so that all the rows are counted? And by extension, what happens during COUNT(DISTINCT *)?

Comment: In most databases, that would simply be a syntax error.  If it is allowed, the `*` would expand to all columns.

Comment: What database system are you using? `COUNT(DISTINCT *)` isn't supported by some, and others may not treat the expression correctly. `COUNT(*)` should *always* return a single value, not "nothing", regardless of the table contents. Your statement may just end up with an (invisible) error.

Comment: Is there any difference in terms of performance using the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE` vs `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE` ?

Comment: @Andres2142: that depends on the DB system you're using, but "no" is a safe bet because neither requires looking at columns at all. It has nothing to do with this question, in any case, since `DISTINCT` really is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a syntax error in most databases.  If it were allowed, it would probably be equivalent to:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct * from t) t
```

However, `NULL` values might throw it off.